# Does intensity of pixel and depth of that pixel follow a specific relation?

Tags: image, algorithm, math, relation, depth

Is there any mathematical relationship between intensity of object and depth of the object ?
if a video is shot while varying the distance of object from camera in each frame will it follow some specific relation .Like disparity is inversely proportional to depth does intensity also follow any such relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is in some cases but the main dependency is not about camera but light/shadow sources.

I assume you want this for image recognition/reconstruction

1. **you have to know the light model**

   directional (Sun) or point light (Lamp)?
2. **fully diffused directional light**

   no matter the distance if you know the source position relative to camera then you can detect surface normals from intensity. For that you either have to know the `albedo` of surface or you see max or min intensity in some gradient on this surface. `max,min` is the `max/min` reflection of light so you can easily compute the vector coordinates ...
3. **point light**

   here the position and orientation matters so add the distance intensity dependency to bullet **#2**. Select homogenous surface take few points from it and match computed intensity of 3 points on plane according to your light model until direction and position of the plane matches ... It is similar to **CORDIC** algorithms
4. **combined**

   this is tricky but doable in some cases but the complexity growth is exponential
5. **shadows**

   casted shadows can reveal direct geometry properties just use reverse ray from shadow edge to light source until it hits obstacle edge ... or if shadow is casted by straight edge and it is curved that also tels a lot ...

**[Notes]**

all bullets are so complex that can fill entire books. I am no expert in this area so take that in mind

Comment: Thanks, that's a very detailed answer. I appreciate the depth of the answer now :)

Comment: @NikitaChopra yep it takes time knowledge and experience to grasp what is behind all the bullets... glad to be of help